# Backup and trimming data idea

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup

Our main table, `tblLink`, will have its primary key as foreign in a few other tables too and one of the tables will be `tblMainData` which over time will be millions of rows.

We would like to maintain only 3 months of data.

The rest we would like to purge and keep to generate history reports. What is the best mechanism to go about in this scenario?

Should we run a cron job to keep deleting data which is more than 3 months old? If so, how can we store it in a `.sql` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `foreign keys` in your tables so you can't go with partitioning directly.As Partitioning does not support foreign keys in MySQL.

You may go with **partitioning** but then you will have to create the work around for that.you have to ensure your integrity by using triggers for **(INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE)** on tables.

***i.e*** Insert into the Child table will only be allowed if the corresponding record exist in Parent table. 
**You have to maintain all these integrity(INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) by using triggers.**

Then you can create the partitioning on table's on a quarter basis and then drop the  partition.

for creating the .sql files you may use `--where` clause with `mysqldump` it will create the backup in .`sql` file format.

You can also create the csv's for your old data for the future reference.

Comment: If you need any information other than this please write..

Comment: There are going to be quite a number of tables link to the tblLink is which the main table to decide on the trimming. So which is the best mechanism to go about I am kind of lost any experience on your side how to solve this problem? I think I should  trim rite rather then just maintain all the old data there?